# GCSE: The straight lines $mx+3y-7=0$ and $2x-ny+8=0$ are parallel. Find $m \cdot n$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

looking please for any help.

The straight lines $mx+3y-7=0$ and $2x-ny+8=0$ are parallel. Find $m \cdot n$.

My attempt was the following:
I replaced $m \to 2$ so from $mx+3y-7=0$;
$2x+3y-7=0$ because  the angular coefficient is the same if two straight lines are parallel, but I don’t know how to find the $n$?!

All help/solutions appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Which country's GCSE is this?

Comment: England.  This excercise is from the book  AQA GCSE Math Higher

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Two lines $ax+by+c=0$ and $ex+fy+g=0$ are parallel if
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{e}{f}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much